# In connected app for salesforce1, What is the difference and individual usage for Info URL, Start URL and Mobile Start URL?

Tags: salesforce1-app, connected-apps

While I was configuring connected app for salesforce1 for my org, I saw Info URL, Start URL and Mobile Start URL under Basic Information section. I found that Info URL is populated by salesforce itself and is not changeable, but when I changed Start URL and Mobile Start URL, it is not producing any effect on the mobile app. i.e. I could still see the same starting page and everything else same in my mobile app. Also when I tried to search for this I found this generic article for connected app [https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_create.htm][1](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_create.htm), but even from here I'm unable to figure out the usage of each of those fields. Can someone please help me understand it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mobile Start URL** - This URL is where you will first be redirected when you use the Connected App from your Mobile Device .If this is not specified then Start URL is used and your app redirects there

**Start URL** - This is where your application using connected app will be redirected after authentication

**Info URL** - If you need to provide more info about your app you will provide a weblink here .

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_create.htm#mobileapp

You are not able to change INFO URL because it is locked once connected app is Packaged as Managed Package .If you create a fresh connected app you should be able to provide your own URL there

Also all this info is applicable if you are creating your own connected app .For Connected apps that are already managed package you will not be able to change most of these things or change should not affect anything .

Comment: Hi @Mohith, Thanks for the info. But does this mean that because salesforce1 is a managed package from salesforce, specifying Mobile Start URL and Start URL will not produce any effect on the mobile app? Just want to verify if I'm understanding it correct.

Comment: @SfdcNovice That's correct .The connected app is managed so should have no affect .